# Accordion JS hyperlink propagation

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, accordion, stoppropagation

I am working on a website with multiple accordions on each page with download links.  I found a beautiful accordion by Ahmet Aksungur, but the hyperlinks don’t work with his code.  I’ve tried adding preventDefault() and stopPropagation() --  $.on('click', 'a', function (e) { e.stopPropegation();}) -- – this work great (once!) – but the problem is that after the initial download, none of the accordions or download links work.
Could anyone suggest a way to stopPropagation on an event and allow normal function of the rest of the accordions.  Thanks.

codepen:  https://codepen.io/doncroy/pen/abZBZyL

'''

```
<script>
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var jQueryPlugin = (window.jQueryPlugin = function (ident, func) {
        return function (arg) {
            if (this.length > 1) {
                this.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this);

                    if (!$this.data(ident)) {
                        $this.data(ident, func($this, arg));
                    }
                });

                return this;
            } else if (this.length === 1) {
                if (!this.data(ident)) {
                    this.data(ident, func(this, arg));
                }

                return this.data(ident);
            }
        };
    });
})();

(function () {
    "use strict";
    function Accordion($roots) {
        var element = $roots;
        var accordion = $roots.first("[data-accordion]");
        var accordion_target = $roots.find("[data-accordion-item]");
        var accordion_content = $roots.find("[data-accordion-content]");
        $(accordion_target).click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("opened");
            $(this).find(accordion_content).slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).siblings().find(accordion_content).slideUp("slow");
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("opened");
        });
    }
    $.fn.Accordion = jQueryPlugin("Accordion", Accordion);
    $("[data-accordion]").Accordion();

    function Ripple_Button($root) {
        var elements = $root;
        var ripple_btn = $root.first("[data-ripple]");
        $(ripple_btn).on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $div = $("<div/>"),
                btnOffset = ripple_btn.offset(),
                xPos = event.pageX - btnOffset.left,
                yPos = event.pageY - btnOffset.top;
            $div.addClass("ripple-effect");
            $div.css({
                height: ripple_btn.height(),
                width: ripple_btn.height(),
                top: yPos - $div.height() / 2,
                left: xPos - $div.width() / 2,
                background: ripple_btn.data("ripple") || "#ffffff26"
            });
            ripple_btn.append($div);

            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $div.remove();
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
    $.fn.Ripple_Button = jQueryPlugin("Ripple_Button", Ripple_Button);
    $("[data-ripple]").Ripple_Button();
})();
</script>
```

'''
'''

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="aks-accordion" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage" data-accordion="">
        <div class="aks-accordion-row">
            <div class="aks-accordion-item" itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question" data-accordion-item="" data-ripple="#2c612c26">
                <div class="aks-accordion-item-row">
                    <div class="aks-accordion-item-icon">
                        <svg class="aks-accordion-item-icon-open" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                            <path d="M492,236H276V20c0-11.046-8.954-20-20-20c-11.046,0-20,8.954-20,20v216H20c-11.046,0-20,8.954-20,20s8.954,20,20,20h216
            v216c0,11.046,8.954,20,20,20s20-8.954,20-20V276h216c11.046,0,20-8.954,20-20C512,244.954,503.046,236,492,236z" />
                        </svg>
                        <svg class="aks-accordion-item-icon-close" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                            <path d="M492,236H20c-11.046,0-20,8.954-20,20c0,11.046,8.954,20,20,20h472c11.046,0,20-8.954,20-20S503.046,236,492,236z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="aks-accordion-item-title">
                        <h4 itemprop="name">Dropdown Title</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="aks-accordion-item-content" itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer" data-accordion-content="">
<li><div id="#" onclick='recordVisit(this.id, "link")'><a href="example.com" download="#"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i>PLACEHOLDER</a></div></li>
<li><div id="#" onclick='recordVisit(this.id, "link")'><a href="example.com" download="#"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i>PLACEHOLDER</a></div></li>
<li><div id="#" onclick='recordVisit(this.id, "link")'><a href="example.com" download="#"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i>PLACEHOLDER</a></div></li> 
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  The problem with the stopPropagation() written into the JS was that it affected the accordions globally.  The solution was to use an inline onclick event on each of the links.

```
<li><div id="#" onclick='recordVisit(this.id, "link"); event.stopPropagation();'><a href="example.com" download="#"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i>PLACEHOLDER</a></div></li>
```